# ScreenTime: macOs Fullscreen Bug?

Tags: video, fullscreen, parental-controls, screen-time

We have configured our kids' devices to use Apple's Screentime limits. This works more or less well on iOS, having disabled Safari because it's per-domain handling of screentime limits is confusing.

On macOS though, the following behaviour occurs often:

- Kid watches Youtube or Netflix in Chrome
- Of course, in fullscreen mode.
- Screentime limits ends, but as the fullscreen video is in another "Space" on the Mac, it somehow doesn't manage to stop the viewing.
- Consequence: Kid watches entire Season if we don't notice it.
- Only after fullscreen mode has been ended, the limit kicks in and kid has to ask for more screen time.

I haven't been able to find anything on this subject. Have you heard of such a bug and/or can you recommend any changes in the settings?

PS: What they often do as well is close the lid of the notebook while the movie is running or only paused but still in fullscreen mode. I have the impression this has also negative effects on ScreenTime, e.g. not stopping measuring time.

Comment: Maybe https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/337035/60854 might help, use Firefox instead of chrome to avoid usage of new Space for the fullscreen mode

Comment: This is an ongoing issue with Chrome\macOS/iOS.  There are [extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screentime/ofmanejijbcohgebmdfacglmhemiifca) that you can use as a workaround, but I second the motion of switching to Firefox.  I’ve “[DeGoogled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DeGoogle)” most of my compute environments and couldn’t be happier.  This will solve your issue.

Comment: @Allan do you have links to resources like bug reports? On Chromium or only chrome?